# How to delete record with jquery in cakephp?

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I am deleting the record with jquery in cakephp.Itries the following code but it is not giving me actual output.It delete the record when i refresh the page.When i click on delete link it give me a popup message.Failed to delete the record.

https://gist.github.com/taleeb35/e61f58af9944511b1669

This is my gist code.

```
public function delete($id = null) {
  if($this->request->is('ajax')) {
    //$this->autoRender = false;
    if ($this->User->delete($id)) {
      $response = $this->Session->setFlash(__('User deleted'));
      $response .= $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    } else {
      $response = $this->Session->setFlash(__('User was not deleted'));
      $response.=  $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    return json_encode($response);
  }  
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.delete').click(function(e) {
        var __this = this;
        e.preventDefault();
        var parent = $(this).parent("td").parent("tr");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: $(__this).attr("href"),
            beforeSend: function() {
                parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},3000);
            },
            success: function(response) {
                if(response.success){
                    parent.slideUp(300,function() {
                        parent.remove();
                    });
                }else{
                    alert("Failed to delete message");
                    parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fff'},1000);//Restore your background back
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It looks like you're just sticking things together without actually knowing what you are doing, and I would strongly suggest that you study the docs first. Neither `setFlash()` not `redirect()` do return anything, also `redirect()` will of course cause a redirect, resulting in the index action output to be returned to the AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a couple things in your action. First, uncomment line with autorender. This action is ajax only, so you don't need to render anything and even view file is not necessary. Second thing is layout, should be set to null or ajax-friendly. The last thing is response and way of returning them. You shuld use `die()` insetad of `return` and it will be better if your response will be array with all informations you need in your js script. So your action could look as follows:

```
public function delete($id = null) {
    if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $this->layout = null;

        $response = array();

        if ($this->User->delete($id)) {
            $response['success'] = false;
            $response['message'] = __('User deleted');
            $response['redirect'] = Router::url(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $response['success'] = true;
            $response['message'] = __('User was not deleted');
            $response['redirect'] = Router::url(array('action' => 'index'));
        }

        echo json_encode($response);
    }

    die();
}
```

The second thing to do is adding type of data returning by ajax call. You can also parse response inside `success` callback.

```
dataType: 'json'
```

or (in success callback)

```
response = JSON.parse(response);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.My delete function actually update(edit not delete) some records in table.At this time tr remove from the screen.when i refresh the page tr comes back with updates result.Now i want how to show the updated record without refreshing the page and also tr should not remove from the page.

Comment: and also how to show confirmation message when record is updated?